# Find shortcuts of an Excel Add-In

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I am currently using a macro designed by a previous coworker in Excel (version 2002). The macro is installed via an excel file saved in \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns. When editing the file, I can't find where the shortcuts are defined. I don't see any "OnKey" function and no assigned macro via the ribbon in  Developer\Macros. I can't find either a function in "ThisWorkbook" in "Microsoft Excel Object", under the project name. Do you have any idea of where I could find these shortcuts?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: if you copy this file to usb and open it in another pc it works?

Comment: In Excel 2002 Ribbon did not exist. Doesn't it have standard modules? If not something confidential, can you share the add-in in discussion? [Here](https://easyupload.io/) it is a free transfer site easy to be used... I will explain what is it about. I will maybe make a Ribbon new Tab with some buttons. What version of Excel do you use now?

Comment: `ALT` + `F8` and then `Options` ?

Comment: @virxen unfortunately no

Comment: @FaneDuru I meant the version 2002 (Build 12527.21104) relased in september 2020

Comment: @RalfS No, it's only the shortcut of Developer\Macros, there is nothing there

Comment: Since you are talking about "ThisWorkbook", I can deduce that you are able to open VBE and see its project. Is that way of understanding correct? I asked you: "Doesn't it have standard modules?" Do you have an answer at this question? Do you know what a standard module is?

Comment: Hi, you would need to check if there is any code inside this excel file. Click " ALT + F11 " to se if there is any code inside any workbook or module.
Tutorial : [link](https://spreadsheeto.com/vba-editor/)
Inside VBA , you should find code of creating shortcuts. 
Tutorial: [link](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=584)
So now you can analize them :). Have fun

Comment: @FaneDuru When I open Microsoft Virtual Basic on an new excel file, I always see two  projects : mine and the Add-in. No, I am not sure what you mean by "standard module"

Comment: When you look inside the add-in project there can be folders: 1. `Microsoft  Excel Objects`, which contains Sheet modules (named as the sheet) and "ThisWorkbook" (where some events exist), 2. `Forms`, where user forms exist, 3. `Modules`, where **Standard modules** exist, 4. `Class Modules`, where class modules exist and 4. `References` if at least a reference to a workbook exists (Personal.xlsb, for instance). But I asked you in my first comment: Is it something confidential in the add-in in discussion? If not, you can share it, or send to me on my personal email account (in my user profile).

Comment: And you do not open Microsoft Visual Basic on a new excel file... You can open VBE (Visual Basic Editor) whenever you want and you may have a lot of projects in its `Project Explorer`...

Comment: Still alive? Did you understand what is it to be checked?

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks a lot for your answer, sorry for the delay. I am not super familiar with the terminology; I know how to code but I usually never start a project from scratch.
In my previous works, I would just use the OneKey function in the Module where I define my function to define a shortcut. Here, I don’t see this function in the modules. When I look in the VBA folder, I can see two items inside the project folder of the add-in: Microsoft Excel Objects and Modules. I don't see the "Standard modules" in "Modules".

Thanks a lot for you help but I can’t send it to you :(

Comment: Then, in that 'Modules' folder you will see the used modules and all Subs, Functions which are used. You can run a Sub, only writing its name in another one, where to be called. I mean, having the Sub named `Sub Test1', you may call it from another Sub, simple writing 'Test1'... No need to see the add-in. You looked confused and I only offered my help to explain what is it about.